# My question is about the concept of acceleration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, acceleration

What would happen to the velocity of an object if it is given an initial acceleration of 2 meter per second per second in a case if there is no dissipating force such as gravity, air resistance or friction. I think its velocity would increase by 2 meter per second after every second and will go on increasing forever. Am I right? please tell me.

Comment: A little comment: gravity is not a dissipative force. It can slow down an object, but it will not cause a loss of mechanical energy, as it converts kinetic energy into potential energy (or vice versa).

Comment: You ask:"an object if it is given an initial acceleration" initial means only in the beginning. you did not say how long or if the acceleration continues forever. Only than the answer of S.A applies.

Answer (score 5):

An object with mass accelerates only if is being pushed by a force.  If the force is removed, the acceleration will stop. The problem with a rocket is that you have to accelerate the fuel until you run out.

Comment: Then how wiil this object come to rest in the absence of any resistive force (force which caused acceleration is removed).

Comment: Also in the absence of gravity

Comment: Or it will not come to rest?

Comment: It will not come "to rest", but it will cease accelerating and continue at the same velocity reached.

Comment: In the absence of all forces, a mass with velocity will continue with that velocity until some force acts to change it.  When traveling in space, you need enough remaining fuel for your rocket to stop when you get where you are going.

Comment: @R.W.Bird You need *some means* to stop yourself - having fuel to burn is one way, but there are others. Running into something extremely heavy (like a planet) works.  Ideally, if the planet has an air cushion, you can hit that instead and slow down gradually enough to not disintegrate.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: The velocity will increase upto a limit and then something cool will start to happen.

A slightly longer answer: In terms of Newtons laws of motion, if acceleration is constant, then the following formula $ v=u+at$ is valid. According to the formula, with increasing time, velocity (v) should just keep on increasing. However, Newtons laws of motion are *only correct at low velocities*.

At higher velocities, these formulas break down and are replaced by formulas predicted by special theory of relativity. The theory predicts that the force (in your case the force which is creating the $2\; \mathrm{m/s^2}$ acceleration) will no longer increase the velocity but will start to increase the mass of the object.

Comment: This answer isn't quite accurate. The acceleration (as measured from some fixed frame) will smoothly decrease -- it isn't like there's some switch that comes on and says "now the velocity is relativistic". Newton's laws of motion are never exactly correct, but they are good approximations at low (relative) velocities.

Comment: Yep, thats true. I should have framed my answer better. Thank you.

Comment: " _will no longer increase the velocity but will start to increase the mass of the object._       "  Are you talking about relativistic mass? isnt that an outdated concept? I thought it is thought to be an inaccurate way of looking at things

Comment: @silverrahul I'd argue is not so much inaccurate, as it is adding additional complexity, since if you utilize the concept you now need to be very carful to distinguish invariant mass and relativistic mass. It also does not fit the preferred view of things where in it is not the object itself changing to need the extra energy, but the structure of spacetime itself requiring the additional energy. One absolutely can utilize the concept in a rigorous and precise manner, but the intuitions it gives may be misleading, and you are adding more complexity than is strictly required.

Comment: I agree that it gives a very misleading intuition

Comment: Downvoted because when you initially bring up relativity, you *must* mention that acceleration is frame dependent. I can't tell from OP if acceleration should be constant in a rest frame or in the comoving frame. If the former, that requires more and more energy, if the latter, the acceleration as seen from a rest frame will gradually appear to go to 0.

Comment: @silverrahul *relativistic mass? isnt that an outdated concept?* Yes, very much so. It is confusing, pointless, and obsolete.

Comment: If relativistic mass is out, what is the current concept that is in use? 
(FYI, I have just begun GTR)

Comment: @S.A Today we use the Lorentz-invariant mass $m$, the relativistic energy $E=\gamma m$ (in units where $c=1$), and the relativistic momentum $\mathbf p=\gamma m\mathbf v$. They are related by $m^2=E^2-\mathbf{p}^2$, which says that the mass is the Lorentz-invariant “length” (magnitude) of the energy-momentum four-vector $p^\mu=(E,\mathbf p)$.